# Android Camera Preview Callback slow down We need the constant fps

Tags: android, camera, frame-rate

Hello folk last few day I faced the issue on Camera Preview Callback, I want to scan the each frame

inside the added PreviewCallback, I have device (motorola g) that give me the 30 fps. below is the

code inside the preview Callback.

```
private PreviewCallback previewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) 
        {

          if (data == null) throw new NullPointerException();
          Camera.Size size = cam.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
          if (size == null) throw new NullPointerException();

          int width = size.width;

          int height = size.height;

            // maximum value of the range of sum (Red) values in each frame 1/10 part of every 5th 
            // pixel red value sum ( if all pixels consider the red(255) then max value of sum of r)
          final double analysisFrameSize = (((width * height)/100)/5f)* 255;

          ImageProcessing.setMaxPixelPerFrame(analysisFrameSize);

          ImageProcessModel model = ImageProcessing.decodeYUV420SPtoRedAvg(data.clone(), width, height);

          List<Integer> furtherAnaylisList = model.getmFurtherAnalysisList();

          final int frameSize = (((width * height)/100)/5);

          int redAvg = (furtherAnaylisList.get(0) / frameSize);

          int green = (furtherAnaylisList.get(1) / frameSize);

          int blue = (furtherAnaylisList.get(2) / frameSize);

          Log.println(TAG,String.format("AvgRed:%2d,AvgGree:%2d,AvgBlue:%2d",redAvg,green,blue));

        }
    };
```

Is program slow down the frame rate inside the preview callback because after write the code it slow down fps 30 fps to  22 fps, I have no issues with 22 fps but it is not constant.

Can I set the camera for give me the 22 or 30 fps constant.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I set the camera for give me the 22 or 30 fps constant.

No, but you could move your image processing work to a background thread, so you stop slowing down the camera.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, I was also tried it but I have issue with camera It give me the 22 to 30 fps can we receive the 30 fps constant after putting the logic in background

Comment: @BhavdipPathar: There is no requirement that the camera give you previews at any particular rate. All you can do is attempt to interfere the least with the camera's operation.

Comment: Actually In background I scan the each frame sample data in my algorithm.

Comment: We have algorithm that need at least 30 sample input for receive the right output.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar: If, without your algorithm, you are getting 30fps, and with your algorithm, you are getting less than 30fps, then your algorithm is the source of the slowdown. If moving it to a background thread is insufficient to clear up the problem, you will need to consider optimizing the algorithm, or running the algorithm offline (capture the data first, analyze it later), or converting the algorithm to C/C++ or RenderScript Compute code so it runs faster.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I was also thought about to apply algorithm offline, but I need the real time output using each frame data by input in to the algorithm, now I have one options put the algorithm in c/c++ might be help

Comment: one last question In the above preview callback of camera, What I did commented the all Processing logic for each frame, then put the frame index once the 30 second complete I show the number of frames index,It show me the very fps in each trial, so It means we can not set it constant.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar: "So It means we can not set it constant" -- correct. It will also vary by hardware.

Comment: The conclusion is put the algorithm logic in the background or try to optimized it with the help of c/c++ for receiving the actual frame rate with out slowing down the preview callback.

Comment: Hi I put the algorithm in background service,What I did in  onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) sent the scan frame to the background running service. I received the larger frame rate but problem is after 20 second it will start drop out the frame rate. I need 30 second recorded frame

Comment: Also I seen in documentation if we need the best performance use addCallbackBuffer

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/experimental/+/ics-mr0/CameraPreviewTest/src/com/example/android/videochatcameratest/VideoChatTestActivity.java

Comment: CommonsWare also  see my questions stackoverflow.com/questions/29645950/… and stackoverflow.com/questions/29649137/